# What is the best way to encourage allies to ward more?

Tags: league-of-legends

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you convince ally players to buy wards in normal games or lower Elo?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/57890/how-do-you-convince-ally-players-to-buy-wards-in-normal-games-or-lower-elo)

:) Hello everyone. I know we've all ran into this situation at least once in our League of Legends careers, as I figured that as my first question, this would be a fine subject to get your input on, fellow summoners.

So, your solo top keeps dying to their jungler, you keep finding the dragon's lair empty, you keep pleading to your team to spend the paltry 75 gold to increase their map awareness, but the map remains dark save for your towers and the few wards you've been able to place without getting destroyed by their fed solo.

How do you convince your team that map awareness is king?

Answer (score 2):

It is very hard to do this due to the fact teammates may still not use that ward due to the fact they do not keep an eye on the mini-map very often, if this is the case they wouldn't listen to any kind of reasoning due to the fact its a waste of gold since they won't benefit from it.

The only way to get them to do is give them reasoning and remind them constantly in a polite way to ward a nearby bush that covers the river, being rude doesn't get anything solved in solo queue afterall :)